# How to highlight image on mouse hoover QML

Tags: image, qt, qml, mousearea

I'm new to QML and I am trying to highlight an image on mouse hoover. I have a row of movie images, like this:

[image]

Here is my code for image number 4 (tarzan):

```
Rectangle{
   id:rect4
   width: parent.width/5-row.spacing/5
   height:parent.height
   color:'transparent'
   Image{
       id: tarzan
       fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
       anchors.fill: parent
       source:'qrc:tarzan.jpg'
       MouseArea{
           id:area
           width:parent.width
           height: parent.height
           hoverEnabled: true
           anchors.fill:parent
           onClicked:tarzan.forceActiveFocus()
       }
```

I tried different ways, but nothing happens. Any ideas? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any code that handles the hovered state. Maybe take a look at the `containsMouse` property and the `entered` and `exited` signals of the MouseArea

Comment: Okay, but why ```onClicked``` doesn't work?

Comment: `onClicked` reacts on an active mouse click and it works for me. The method `.forceActiveFocus()` of Image does not hightlight the image, so you'd have to implement another way of highlighting that image

Comment: I tried ```onClicked: console.log("Button clicked!")```  and nothing happens also.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved it using entered and exited signals. Inside I used ```tarzan.scale=1.2``` and it worked. The image changes size when i hoover over it with mouse.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do this if you are using the qt quick version 2.15

```
import QtQuick 2.15
```

you can use the HoverHandler object something like this

```
Image{
       id: tarzan
       fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
       anchors.fill: parent
       source:'qrc:tarzan.jpg'
       HoverHandler{
          onHoveredChanged: {
              if(hovered){
                  tarzan.scale = 1.2
              }
              else{
                  tarzan.scale = 1
              }
          }

      }
```

if you are using qtquick anything below 2.15 then your mousearea object should look something like this

Then it would be something like this the mouse area code

```
MouseArea{
           id:area
           width:parent.width
           height: parent.height
           hoverEnabled: true
           anchors.fill:parent
           onContainsMouseChanged: {
              if(containsMouse){
                  tarzan.scale = 1.2
              }
              else{
                  tarzan.scale = 1
              }
          }
           onClicked:tarzan.forceActiveFocus()
       }
```

Comment: why not `scale: area.containsMouse ? 1.2 : 0` before `id: tarzan`

Comment: Yes, we can do this as well but, I Used the if else to keep it simple, and answer the questions using the same objects, if we make the scale of the image zero, the image would disappear hence. if you just want a zooming effect making the scale zero is not recommended

Comment: In QML, binding is preferred over if-else since it has certain advantages such as: The code is more readable, resources are saved since the language optimizes this type of operations, etc.